# How to add custom action button on grid acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello i have search alot on how i can do this but i cant seem to make it work.
so i want to add an action button on my grid. 
i want to add calculate price on here on the circle
[image]

```
 public PXAction<PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity> CalcPrice;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "CalculatePrice")]
    protected void calcPrice()
    {

    }
```

i added my action button on my graph
and then i put a button on the grid right here

but its not working i put it on document detail tab then i added a button am i doing it right?
thank you in advance for helping me
[image]

Comment: can't tell exactly from the screenshot. but did you add the action in the correct grid ?

Comment: There is an entry on the grid that needs to go in the page. Compare to the buttons above the transactions grid to compare and get the entry you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try somethink like that

```
public PXAction<PRPayroll> Calculate;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Calculate")]
public virtual IEnumerable calculate(PXAdapter adapter)
{
   return adapter.Get();
}
```

and in the .aspx add this one

```
<ActionBar ActionsText="True">
    <CustomItems>
        <px:PXToolBarButton>
        <AutoCallBack Command="Calculate" Target="ds" >
             </AutoCallBack>
        </px:PXToolBarButton>
    </CustomItems>
</ActionBar>
```